# Changing the format of nested xaxis ticks labels for the boxplot chart

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I want to change the format of the nested xaxis ticks labels for boxplot chart (`major`, `group` and `subgroup` in terms of [`bokeh.models.CategoricalAxis`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html#bokeh.models.CategoricalAxis) attributes).

The following code is based on https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/boxplot_chart.html

```py
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import dim
hv.extension('bokeh')

from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df
title = "MPG by Cylinders and Data Source, Colored by Cylinders"
boxwhisker = hv.BoxWhisker(df, ['cyl', 'origin'], 'mpg', label=title)
boxwhisker.opts(show_legend=False, width=600, box_fill_color=dim('origin').str(), cmap='Set1')
```

[image]

I want to change the format of the nested `group`-axis ticks labels (`cyl`-level).

If I change `figure.xaxis.formatter` the `major` axis (`origin`-level) format is changed:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter
figure = hv.render(boxwhisker)
figure.xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="000")
show(figure)
```

[image]

But I can't find the attributes (or any other way) to change `group`-axis ticks labels format (`cyl`-level). Smth like `figure.x axis.major_label_orientation` for `major`-axis ticks label orientation and `figure.x axis.group_label_orientation` for `group`-axis ticks label orientation.

Maybe this problem requires a very specific (custom) solution, for example pass `x_range` parameter while initializing `bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=bokeh.models.FactorRange(...))` (seen on https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/bars.html#nested-categories ).
Also I read that categorical ranges is sequences of strings ([here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/bars.html#bar-charts)). So I have to convert my dataframe columns for xaxis as strings in the format I need.